# Name cannot begin with the '$' character, hexadecimal value 0x24

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have this warning that never goes away and I don't know how to get it fixed:

> Warning        Name cannot begin with the '$' character, hexadecimal value 0x24.
>
> .Android  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets   1668    Build

After enabling detailed verbosity, it points to this section of the Xamarin.Android.Common.targets file:

```xml
<Target Name="_GenerateJavaStubs" DependsOnTargets="_SetLatestTargetFrameworkVersion;_PrepareAssemblies;$(_AfterPrepareAssemblies)" Inputs="$(MSBuildAllProjects);@(_ResolvedAssemblies);$(_AndroidManifestAbs);$(_AndroidBuildPropertiesCache)" Outputs="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\AndroidManifest.xml;$(_AcwMapFile);$(_AndroidTypeMappingJavaToManaged);$(_AndroidTypeMappingManagedToJava)">
  <GenerateJavaStubs ResolvedAssemblies="@(_ResolvedAssemblies)" ResolvedUserAssemblies="@(_ResolvedUserAssemblies)" ManifestTemplate="$(_AndroidManifestAbs)" MergedManifestDocuments="@(ExtractedManifestDocuments)" Debug="$(AndroidIncludeDebugSymbols)"
    NeedsInternet="$(AndroidNeedsInternetPermission)" AndroidSdkPlatform="$(_AndroidApiLevel)" AndroidSdkDir="$(_AndroidSdkDirectory)" PackageName="$(_AndroidPackage)" ManifestPlaceholders="$(AndroidManifestPlaceholders)" OutputDirectory="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android"
    MergedAndroidManifestOutput="$(IntermediateOutputPath)android\AndroidManifest.xml" UseSharedRuntime="$(AndroidUseSharedRuntime)" EmbedAssemblies="$(EmbedAssembliesIntoApk)" ResourceDirectory="$(MonoAndroidResDirIntermediate)" BundledWearApplicationName="$(BundledWearApplicationPackageName)"
    PackageNamingPolicy="$(AndroidPackageNamingPolicy)" ApplicationJavaClass="$(AndroidApplicationJavaClass)" AcwMapFile="$(_AcwMapFile)">
  </GenerateJavaStubs>
  <ConvertResourcesCases ResourceDirectories="$(MonoAndroidResDirIntermediate)" AcwMapFile="$(_AcwMapFile)" />
</Target>
```

I have no idea if I need to modify this or if one of my files is causing the issue. I double checked, none of my files actually start with a $.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: It seems that your `.xml` or `.axml` is malformed or wrong, please check it.

Comment: York Shen, thnaks for your answer but that .xml file is made my Xamarin. I don't know wjhat to look for. It seems fine.

Comment: You could press `Ctrl` and `F` at same time, search "$" in your `Current project`.

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Comment: Hi York. Nope still have the warning. I already searched for "$". My project contains exacly zero "$" symbols. None of my filenames have "$" in it.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo that could reproduce this problem? Troubleshooting this issue will be much easier if I have a simple project.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution?

Comment: You should be able to reproduce if you creare a Xamarin.Form project with at least Android as a platform

Comment: Is there any solution? Im getting frustrated because it cant build my project

Comment: No, but this warning was not stopping me from building. I think it's just a warning that Visual Studio considers as a warning but that Android is totaly fine with. Are you sure you don't have any other errors newbieguy?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a Xamarin bug, at least in some circumstances. Logged Github issues [here](https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/114) and [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/1698) with repro steps and a sample project.

Answer (score 0):

### **Try this:**

1. Open **Windows Task Manager** -> Go to the **Details** Tab
2. **End** all `MSBuild.exe` tasks you may find

---

[image: End MSBuild.exe]

---

3. Go to your project folder, **delete** `Bin` & `Obj` folders `(SHIFT+DEL)`
4. **Close** Visual Studio completely
5. Open Visual Studio again, open your solution, **rebuild**.

### **OR this:**

1. Open Project settings
2. Go to **Android Manifest**
3. Make sure your **Version number** doesn't have `dots` or `commas`

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the diagnostic output of Visual Studio, I could see a lot of '\$' occurrences, most of them related to Google Play.

For me, the solution was that I had forgotten to install Google Play in the SDK Manager (under Extras).

Comment: Google play services,APK ?

Answer (score 0):

For me, a Visual Studio 2017 update did the trick.
Now it is only a warning anymore.

> Name cannot begin with the '$' character, hexadecimal value 0x24.

VS 17 update from 15.4.4 to 15.7.4 was done.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this error on Android, and what I have done to make it works is: "Version Number" should be a number and it should not contain the dot.